# Mysql Percentage Calculation

Tags: mysql

I would need anyone to help with this code

```
SELECT staff.id
     , staff.fullname AS StaffName
     , (SELECT payroll_structure.percentage 
          FROM payroll_structure 
         WHERE payroll_structure.name = 'Basic'
       ) / 100 * salaries.amount AS Basic 
  FROM staff 
     , salaries 
 WHERE staff.id = salaries.staff_id 
 ORDER 
    BY staff.id ASC
```

I wish to pull all the values in `payroll_structure.percentage` and use it to calculate the percentage of `salaries.amount` in such that when additional data is entered in `payroll_structure.percentage` the data should be calculated percentage automatically.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't too clear to me so I make some assumptions here:

- payroll_structure has a foreign key to staff. It means each staff has a payroll structure.
- I don't know what percentage means in the payroll_structure table but I did the same math as yours in the question.

Hope this answers your question:

```
SELECT st.id, st.name, ps.percentage /100 * sa.amount FROM staff st JOIN salaries sa on st.id = sa.staff_id
JOIN payroll_structure ps ON ps.staff_id = st.id and ps.name = 'Basic'
ORDER BY st.id;
```

Comment: The mysql statement in my question is correct if i'm to follow that approach. The issue I'm having is on the `WHERE` clause assuming I have `Basic`, `Hosing`, `Transport` in my `payroll_structure` and I want to get the percentage salary of Housing which I have the value in `ps.percentage` how do I loop through them to calculate the value for all staff using where clause for example.

Comment: Can you post your tables so I better understand them?